# Rewriting the values in a dictionary automatically from a function's output

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to code a guessing game in Python. I have a function called bingo_calculator() that takes a 12-character Y/N string as a parameter (i.e. YNNYNNYNYYYN) from a dictionary value and then returns an integer value based on the rules of the game.

My approach is to make a copy of the the dictionary (so that the original guesses are not overwritten) and have the function calculate the integer value and replace the string in the copied dictionary with the new calculated value. From there, I want to sort the integers in descending order. I cannot figure out how to make it so that the values of the dictionary update corresponding to the output of the function automatically.

```
bingo_entries_190_copy = bingoGuesses190.bingo_entries_190.copy() #makes a copy of the dictionary
for value in bingo_entries_190_copy.values():
       print(bingo_calculator(value)) # outputs the integers on the terminal
```

Here's a sample of the dictionary:

```
bingo_entries_190_copy = {

    'Craig': 'NNNNNYNYNYYY',
    'Hirohito': 'YNNNNNNYNYNN',
    'Elemér': 'NYNNYNYYNYYY',
    'Muddy': 'NNYNYNYYNNYY',
    'Kamen': 'NNNNNYYYYYYN',
    'Hiram': 'NNYNNNYNNNYY',
    'Rin': 'NYNNNYYBYNNN',
    'Gessica':  'YNNNNYNYNYNN',
    'Pavlina': 'NNNYNYNNNNYY'
}
```

The desired output would be:

```
bingo_entries_190_copy = {

    'Muddy': 480,
    'Pavlina': 430
    'Hiram': 380,
    'Craig': 160,
    'Elemér': 160,
    'Hirohito': 30,
    'Gessica':  10,
    'Kamen': -30,
    'Rin': -110,

}
```

where the integers are returned when the 12-character Y/N strings are passed through bingo_calculator(). And then I need these entries sorted in descending order based on the integers.

What do I do?

Comment: could you please add a sample of that dictionary, together with a desired output? Makes it easier to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
guess_results = {}
for key in bingoGuesses190:
    guess_results[key] = bingo_calculator(bingoGuesses190[key])
```

To simultaneously print and sort the dictionary in descending order based on the integer values:

```
for entry in sorted(guess_results, key=guess_results.get, reverse=True):
    print(entry, guess_results[entry])
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Is there any way to simultaneously print and sort the dictionary in descending order based on the integer values?

Comment: Of course!  I edited the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply map a new value to each of the name keys in the dictionary. Here's how I'd edit your code to do that:

```
bingo_entries_190_copy = bingoGuesses190.bingo_entries_190.copy() #makes a copy of the dictionary
for key in bingo_entries_190_copy.keys():
       bingo_entries_190_copy[key] = bingo_calculator(bingo_entries_190_copy[key])
```

I hope that helped:)